# MongoDB dynamic values

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb, nosql

So, maybe I've understood something wrong, because I'm from the SQL world: I have a collection with goods:

```
_id: "0234weasq43rq",
title: "Panasonic",
descr: "blah blah",
price: 132,
specifications {
   weight: 135,
   color: "black",
   type: "LCD",
   diagonal: 50
}

_id: "0234weasq43rq",
title: "Samsung Galaxy Tab",
descr: "blah blah",
price: 132,
specifications {
   weight: 135,
   color: "white",
   standard: "GSM",
   wifi: "Yes"
}
```

Can I have different specifications for different categories of goods (e.g. phones and computers)? Are there any problems finding goods using a query like `goods.find(specifications { diagonal: 50 })`, if not all of goods have a "diagonal" specification?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your documents, even in the same collection, may have completely different structures. In your example, the query would return just the goods that have diagonal = 50, and omit any documents that don't have diagonal defined (or that have it defined but it is not 50, obviously)

Comment: Okay, one more question: can i use greater than / less than operators for this query example (ex: specifications{diagonal:{ $gt:3}}) ?

Comment: yes, you can. you can actually test all this in the mongo shell. it is quite easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I keep different specifications for different categories of goods
>   (ex. phones and computers)?

Same collection can have documents with different structures. So for you case you can keep different specifications for different categories of goods.

> Are there any trouble for finding goods using query like
>   goods.find(specifications { diagonal: 50 }), if not all of goods have
>   a "diagonal" specification?

No, absolutely. One thing that may be useful for you is a  [sparse](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes#Indexes-sparse%3atrue) indexes for fields that's not presented in all documents (diagonal field for instance). This index will not include documents that's do not have this field.